# Entity Framework фильтр данных

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

```
    switch (searchBy)
    {
        case "byName" :
            model = db.Movies.Where(m => m.Name.StartsWith(searchText)).ToList();
            break;

        case "byActor":
            model = db.Movies.Select(m => m.Actors.ForEach(x => x.Name.StartsWith(searchText))).ToList();
            break;
    }

public class Actor
{
    public Actor()
    {
        Movies = new List<Movie>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
}

public class Movie
{
    public Movie()
    {
        Genres = new List<Genre>();
        Actors = new List<Actor>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }

    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Actor> Actors { get; set; }
}
```

Всем привет, недавно начал осваивать .net mvc - возник вопрос выборки данных из БД. Нужно сделать выборку всех фильмов в которых есть соответствующие запросу актеры (input text value). Причем имя актера не должно строго соответствовать данным в базе (StartWith).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
switch (searchBy)
        {
            case "byName" :
                model = db.Movies.Where(m => m.Name.Contains(searchText) && 
                    (countryId == null ? true : m.Country.Id == countryId)  &&
                    (genreId == null ? true : m.Genres.Any(a => a.Id == genreId))).ToList();
                break;

            case "byActor":
                model = db.Movies.Where(m => m.Actors.Any(a => a.Name.Contains(searchText)) &&
                    (countryId == null ? true : m.Country.Id == countryId) &&
                     (genreId == null ? true : m.Genres.Any(a => a.Id == genreId))).ToList();
                break;
        }
```

Разобрался - вроде работает, конечная поисковая форма.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]